# Transaction Malleability in the blockchain

Tags: transactions, blockchain, transaction-malleability

How does a transaction malleability look like in the blockchain? Are there any examples?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is Transaction Malleability?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/21994/what-is-transaction-malleability)

Answer (score 8):

Here is example: https://blockchain.info/tx/683f45578328242a06bc5c54acbcbe6e70a5435b4561fc8b0570a59ab09f8bfa?show_adv=true

Look at first input script in raw:

```
4d49003046022100847361c694421bf63ea1b51d8e2189805b161ab3d4cb96ab745a20468dd6c2ea0221009160897652bedfd7c837855d793c32509063338ac7524b8f09abfed761cf16fc014d410004c8dde23708932059bf4491c96794c5412b1182d62d2741e0986cb87276d3053f0b7326155114ad67c04adc60b5a47718fa8744ecb86a001f99da8761113edb24
```

Look at first byte: `4d` (OP_PUSHDATA2). It means, that next 2 bytes contains length of data, that will be pushed to stack. This length = `0x49`. But typical transaction does not use OP_PUSHDATA2 command. If transaction was created by bitcoin-qt, it starts with length of data directly:

```
[4d]49[00]3046....
```

I take into brackets unnecessary bytes.

So, someone added 2 bytes to signature script, but did not break signature and changed id of transaction. Original tx was deleted from blockchain.info. Next link no longer works: https://blockchain.info/tx/ef74c1cbf0003fc4e96a87a59838f7dd3da488d9d83fec3f270b0d3d7c2bc309?show_adv=true

Look at wiki for more information about scripts: https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Script

Comment: Interesting analysis of the raw bytes.

Comment: The ef74 transaction no longer appears on blockchain.info; your link leads to a message saying "Transaction not found".

Comment: Looks like blockchain does not save tx, which is not included in blocks.

Comment: @Zergatul, Where did you grab this tx from?

Comment: I run parser and found this tx in my local blockchain.

Answer (score 6):

The blockchain cannot contain malleable transactions. The malleable transactions happen *before* the transaction is embedded in a block in the blockchain.

Essentially, the transaction ID is a hash of everything about the transaction including the signature. The signature signs everything *except* the signature part (it can't sign its own data). So, two transaction records can have the same inputs and outputs, with (effectively) the same signature, but have a different transaction ID. It is this double transaction ID for the same transaction that can confuse some Bitcoin clients.

After a transaction is incorporated into a block, the malleability no longer matters. When Bitcoin clients try to work with transactions before they have been properly confirmed (by being incorporated in a block several times), problems can arise.

Comment: So inside the block the transaction will definitely have the same ID as when it was created?

Comment: No, transaction will have another ID. I do not agree with Greg Hewgill, trying to found such tx in blockchain now.

Comment: @D-32 When the transaction is created one gets a transactionID, however, the ID can be changed until it is confirmed in a block. If the ID is changed one or the either may be accepted. When somebody expects transactionID **A** to make it into a block, but transactionId **B** is accepted, and they just check for the transactionId **A** they will not find it confirmed. Once the transaction is in a block the transactionId cannot change anymore.

Comment: This is dangerously incorrect! **The block can be orphaned.** And if that block is orphaned and a mutant is in the winning chain, **your entire chain of succeeding transactions will jam** because the immediate successors refer to the wrong transaction ID in their inputs and the indirect successors refer to transactions that can never confirm. This is *precisely* the mistake that screwed over high-volume transaction issuers.