# How did blockr.io see this?

Tags: transaction-malleability, blockexplorer

Here's the pushed/broacast-ed tx http://tbtc.blockr.io/tx/info/d8e5dac095d5f6133e6c3f11e1d9f923c04dac0824f9f8ce0000573df7cc8080

txid was [malleated](https://bitcoin.org/en/glossary/malleability) to txid (when the tx was added into the block):

http://tbtc.blockr.io/tx/info/a9607981ae4bbf42ed0cfacc05455f9396c85a9e8aeb61474f3f7516c35430ec

I am watching all utx broadcasted on the testnet3 network using https://github.com/bitpay/bitcore-p2p

I did not see `a9607981ae4bbf42ed0cfacc05455f9396c85a9e8aeb61474f3f7516c35430ec` broadcast-ed I only saw `d8e5dac095d5f6133e6c3f11e1d9f923c04dac0824f9f8ce0000573df7cc8080`

How the hell did blockr.io see both the original broadcasted tx *and* the altered tx *when it never was seen on the network?*

What voo-doo magic is this?

Look, blockcypher didn't store the original broadcasted txid:
https://api.blockcypher.com/v1/btc/test3/txs/d8e5dac095d5f6133e6c3f11e1d9f923c04dac0824f9f8ce0000573df7cc8080

but they did store the malleated version:

https://api.blockcypher.com/v1/btc/test3/txs/a9607981ae4bbf42ed0cfacc05455f9396c85a9e8aeb61474f3f7516c35430ec

HOW?

related: [How confirm my own doublespend transaction got confirmed](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/52539/how-confirm-my-own-doublespend-transaction-got-confirmed) and [testnet3 frequent tx malleability](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/52571/testnet3-frequent-tx-malleability)

Answer (score 1):

> I did not see `a9607981ae4bbf42ed0cfacc05455f9396c85a9e8aeb61474f3f7516c35430ec` broadcast-ed I only saw `d8e5dac095d5f6133e6c3f11e1d9f923c04dac0824f9f8ce0000573df7cc8080`

That might not be meaningful. Bitcoin is a gossip network, so it's possible for a different node to see a transaction that you didn't see, particularly if it contradicts a transaction you have.

If you're connected to 8 nodes, and each of those has transaction TX1 in their memory pool, none of them will send you TX2 if it contradicts TX1. (Assuming they're running Bitcoin Core, of course.)

Comment: so i need to 'pool' (https://github.com/bitpay/bitcore-p2p/blob/master/docs/pool.md) more nodes to have a greater chance of seeing it?

Comment: 'particularly if it contradicts a transaction you have' - please elaborate!

Comment: @BenMuircroft If two transactions spend the same outpoint, they cannot both succeed. One or more must not get into the chain.

Comment: 'none of them will send you TX2 if it contradicts TX1' - but if TX2 was the malleated transaction altered and included in the block by the miner then *race conditions don't matter* so; the none of them sending TX2 is retarded because the logic will always be ignored by the miners choice of what inevitably goes in!

Comment: @BenMuircroft Yes, that's correct.

Comment: wow that is a major exception! it is occuring like mad frequently right now on testnet3!

Comment: If a wallet sends raw tx 
[4d]49[00]3046....
without [in brackets unnecessary bytes] do you think some miners might be resigning the tx with the unnecessary bytes? therefore changing the txid?!

Comment: related: http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/22058/14316